# Run two Commands and Animation on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, grid

In my app, I have a `Left Grid` and a `Right Grid`. Initially, the `Left Grid` is fully expanded (`GridLength = 7*`) while the `Right Grid` is not visible (`Width = 0*`).

If a `Button` in the `LeftGrid` is clicked and the `Right Grid` is NOT expanded, the `Right Grid` should expand to a `Width` of `3*`.

If the `Right Grid` is expanded and a `Button` in the `LeftGrid` is clicked twice successively, then the `RightGrid` should shrink back to a `Width` of `0*`.

These expansions/contractions should be `Animated`.

When a `Button` is clicked, three things must happen.

1) The `id` of the selected `Button` should be stored in a `Property` in the `ViewModel`.

2) The `Width` to which the `RightGrid` will be set, is stored in a `Property` in the `ViewModel`. This `Command` takes care of the two successive click case.

3) Finally, the `Animation` should run.

I am experiencing a few issues:

1) How do I bind the two `Commands` to a single `Button`?

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top"                        
   Command="{Binding DataContext.SetSelectedItemCommand, 
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
             AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
             CommandParameter="{Binding id}"
             Command="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.ChangeRightGridWidthCommand}"          
>
```

This is not allowed.

I've been looking at this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25808/Aggregating-WPF-Commands-with-CommandGroup).

However, I'm not certain if this will work for me as I am defining my `Commands` in my `ViewModel`.

2) I am using a Custom `GridLength` Animation class as I need to use `*` for my `Widths`.

```
public class GridLengthAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "To", typeof(GridLength), typeof(GridLengthAnimation));

    public GridLength To
    {
        get { return (GridLength)GetValue(ToProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ToProperty, value); }
    }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(GridLength); }
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new GridLengthAnimation();
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(
        object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue,
        AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
         return new GridLength(To.Value,
            GridUnitType.Star);
    }
}
```

I plan on using something like this in my `XAML`:

```
<proj:GridLengthAnimation
          Storyboard.TargetName="rightGrid"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
          To="RightGridWidth" Duration="0:0:2" />

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Name="leftGrid"  Width="7*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Name="rightGrid" Width="{Binding RightGridWidth}"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Should I put the above `XAML` code within:

```
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
```

If so, will my `Commands` or the `EventTrigger` be run first? I need my `Commands` to be run first as only then will the `To` value have been set correctly when the `Storyboard` runs.

I'm quite confused as to how to put all this together.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty with what you already have, i.e. the EventTrigger that runs the animation.

Add a `RightGridWidth` property (with change notification) to your view model:

```
public GridLength RightGridWidth
{
    get { return rightGridWidth; }
    set
    {
        rightGridWidth = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("RightGridWidth");
    }
}
```

Toggle the property value in the `SetSelectedItemCommand`'s execute handler:

```
if (RightGridWidth.Value == 0d)
{
    RightGridWidth = new GridLength(3d, GridUnitType.Star);
}
else
{
    RightGridWidth = new GridLength(0d, GridUnitType.Star);
}
```

Run the animation in the `Click` EventTrigger:

```
<Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding SetSelectedItemCommand}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <local:GridLengthAnimation
                        Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=col2}"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                        Duration="0:0:1" To="{Binding RightGridWidth}"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Finally, use a working implementation of the animation's `GetCurrentValue`, which has to return a value that depends on the `CurrentProgress`:

```
public override object GetCurrentValue(
    object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue,
    AnimationClock animationClock)
{
    var from = (GridLength)defaultOriginValue;

    if (from.GridUnitType != To.GridUnitType ||
        !animationClock.CurrentProgress.HasValue)
    {
        return from;
    }

    var p = animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value;

    return new GridLength(
        (1d - p) * from.Value + p * To.Value,
        from.GridUnitType);
}
```

---

An entirely different and perhaps better approach would be the use of *visual states*. See [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Clemens. The slight issue I face with this is when I initially alter `RightGridWidth` using `SetSelectedItemCommand`, `from` in `GetCurrentValue()` is already set to `3` but the `To` value is still on `0`. After the initial `click` however, it seems to run fine.

Comment: It isn't a perfect solution anyway, as it splits the behaviour into toggling the animation target value in the command handler and starting the animation in an EventTrigger. My suggestion would still be to do all that in a Button Click handler in code behind.

Comment: I didn't know about the existence of the `VisualStateManager` that you mentioned.  Do you think I could use this and still be able to implement the logic I mentioned in my question?

Comment: I guess so. You might just give it a try. Declare two distinct visual states, with two different widths for the right grid, and toggle between them.